# Is there a Wordpress Plugin that allows voting "does this coupon work" on specific links like Retailmenot

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am looking for a way/plugin to allow visitors to vote on specific links (does this coupon work/does this coupon not work) like Retailmenot.

I can only think of the Wordpress Plugin: Wordpress Pods.  I was hoping to find an easier implementation.

Comment: You could use [Vote It Up](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/), however, it doesn't have down-votes. Adding down votes shouldn't be  hard though.

Comment: @Zack Vote It Up has down voting.

Comment: Recently I had to use Vote It up for a client, it was not an option but client requirement (otherwise I would not have used it). It had many bugs, so I fixed some of them but there are still many things to be fixed, here is the github url, if you like you can use it. It does work with Wordpress 3.2: https://github.com/hameedullah/Vote-It-Up

Answer (score 1):

I would use [vote it up](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vote-it-up/), it does support two way voting but can be a bit buggy about accurate tracking of votes